# How X.509 certificate is verified

Tags: ssl, https, cryptography, x509, pki

I'm trying to understand how TLS protocol works under the hood. I know the TLS handshake is based on X.509 certificate. The certificate includes the public key and authenticates it's origin by CA's digital signature.

But how is the certificate verified by the browser according to CA's digital signature? Does browser has the public key of the CA to verify the signature? Isn't it possible for attacker to forge the certificate, if he can tamper the verifying process itself?

Comment: Sorry, but for someone with an over 2k reputation this is surprisingly off-topic. Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Understanding how a security protocol works is a noble goal but definitely too broad and too far removed from programming. There is a ton of material online about SSL/TLS to get you more up to speed. Then, if you have a more specific question you should consider the security or crypto stackexchange sites.

Comment: This isn't really a programming Q and would fit better on security.SX where https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/ is considered canonical but there are many others also. In short, yes the client program or (more often) OS/platform has a 'trust store' of CA identities and publickeys and some other attributes, usually in the form of self-signed certificates.